# django-cms entries giving "page not found" errors

Tags: django, django-cms

Suddenly some of the pages I had already previously created and published are returning "not found" errors. Republishing them does not solve the issue. No error logs, just the following apache log:

```
[Wed Jul 17 12:37:18 2013] [error] /var/www/cms/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/urls/defaults.py:3: DeprecationWarning: django.conf.urls.defaults is deprecated; use django.conf.urls instead
[Wed Jul 17 12:37:18 2013] [error]   DeprecationWarning)
[Wed Jul 17 12:37:18 2013] [error] /var/www/cms/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mptt/models.py:305: DeprecationWarning: Implicit manager CMSPlugin.tree will be removed in django-mptt 0.6.  Explicitly define a TreeManager() on your model to remove this warning.
[Wed Jul 17 12:37:18 2013] [error]   DeprecationWarning
[Wed Jul 17 12:37:18 2013] [error] /var/www/cms/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:827: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2013-07-17 12:37:18.775099) while time zone support is active.
[Wed Jul 17 12:37:18 2013] [error]   RuntimeWarning)
[Wed Jul 17 12:37:18 2013] [error] WARNING 2013-07-17 12:37:18,825 base 19632 140515393550304 Not Found: /en/departments/
```

Any possible reason for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally my problem wasn't about the timezone support. Deep into my code, I had a generator with a get_object_or_404() call. This wasn't supposed to be triggered, but due to trash data that was actually the case.

So, next time check your data first.

Answer (score 1):

You have different warnings for different issues there.

The first warning `DeprecationWarning: django.conf.urls.defaults is deprecated; use django.conf.urls instead` is due to a change in the Django framework code itself. As it tells you, the module `django.conf.urls.defaults` is deprecated and you should use `django.conf.urls` instead, so substituting that in your code will fix it. That is not causing anyway your Django CMS pages not being shown, BTW.

The second is another deprecation warning raised due to some changes in Django CMS code. You must take a look in the [upgrade notes](http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/upgrade.html#treemanager-is-now-the-default-manager-yourmodel-tree-removed) in order to workaround this issue. That is not causing your CMS pages problem neither.

The third warning, `DateTimeField received a naive datetime while time zone support is active` is raised because you are not using time zones support properly. First of all, ensure that you have installed `pytz` package by `pip install pytz`. Then, for example, you should use the `timezone` module to get `now()` timestamps, instead of the `datetime`. Please, take a look on the [Django Time Zones documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/timezones/) to fix that issue, since we can't see where in your project code time stamps are being used.

Looking at the last warning, it seems that the issue with your missing CMS pages takes place somewhere in the timestamps.

Comment: Hi Jose, thanks for your detailed response and sorry for the delay on answering! That sounds quite reasonable, but the only places where I am making use of datetime are into the south migrations! I mean, the .py files generated by south, and which I have already applied some time ago. Should I worry about these? In such case, should I rollback those migrations?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem.

The problem in my case was that the **parent page** was not published. Parent pages have to be published in order for the subpages to be found.

Comment: Yes, not publishing the parent page can be an issue as well.